# Using left join is causing my record to be shown multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using left join in my query, and for some reason it's showing the record multiple times. The problem seems to be the LEFT join for storage accounts,

as there are 4 records in there with the same warehouse, its showing the record 4 times.

My query is

```
SELECT portfolioid, cases, bottles, size, trading, Wine_Name, Wine_Vintage,  storageid,dutystatus,packagingtype,rotation,storageid,color, warehouseid,name,
  wines.*,

    wineinfo.*,
    storageaccounts.*
FROM (`portfolio`)
LEFT JOIN wines ON wines.wine_id = portfolio.wine_id
LEFT JOIN storage ON storage.warehouseid = portfolio.storageid
LEFT JOIN storageaccounts ON storageaccounts.warehouse = portfolio.storageid
LEFT JOIN wineinfo ON wineinfo.wine_id = portfolio.wine_id AND wineinfo.Vintage = portfolio.Wine_Vintage
WHERE portfolio.userID = '$userID'
```

The users set their warehouses in the storageaccounts table, so here will have the same warehouse however unique userIDs. but some rows for the column warehouse will be the same,

What is the best way to stop it showing the main record 4 times because of this?

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT portfolioid, cases,.....`. You will need to check if you are getting the desired output with this. This is all that can be suggested based on the problem described.

Comment: well, which one of the 4 would you like to get in your result?, what would be the logic to choosing one over the others?

Comment: I tried select DISTINCT, did nothing. @Lamak, there is one record in the portfolio with portfolioid. Thats what it should be showing, just the one, but i am trying to grab info from the storageaccounts table using warehouse column. so it is printing the record 4 times.

Comment: yes, and I'm asking which one of the 4 rows from the other table you want to get?

Comment: If distinct didn't work, then there's some value in your result that is unique, causing multiple records to return.  You can try to group by the columns that you want to 'bucket' your results into. Group By doesn't require any sort of aggregate function in your select.

Comment: You have selected all columns from all the joined tables. I'm sure there must be some columns where are different. Share the schema with sample data if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general SQL troubleshooting procedure that might help:

1. When practical, group projected columns by table and use "tablename.columnname" syntax.  The order in which the groups appear should be the same as the order in which the tables appear in your FROM ... JOIN ... clauses.
2. Put each column on a single line after the SELECT keyword.
3. Add calculated columns "1 AS dummy_start," as the first column and "1 AS dummy_end" as the last column.  (The first can reside on the same line as SELECT)
   *Note: we can argue all day whether commas should go at the start or end.  I like them at the start.  You do you.

The end result is something like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS dummy_start,
       table1.id1
       table1.column11,
       table1.column12,
       table1.column13,
       table2.id2
       table2.column21,
       table2.column22,
       table3.id3
       table3.column31,
       1 AS dummy_end
  FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id2 = table2.id2
 INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.id3 = table3.id3
 ORDER BY table1.id1
```

For some reason, you're getting unexpected duplicate rows with the same id1.  It's simple as pie to comment out all references to table2 and/or table3.  I tend to *start* with all joined tables commented out and then add them in (i.e. uncomment the relevant lines) one at a time.  When you see the first set of duplicates, you'll know that the table you just added was the *probably* the culprit.